# NFSv3 mount options to influence WRITE Calls as FILE_SYNC or UNSTABLE

Tags: nfs, mount

In the NFSv3 protocol (https://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1813/27.htm), a WRITE Call can be FILE_SYNC, DATA_SYNC, or UNSTABLE.  Are those options influenced by any mount parameters, e.g. mount -t nfs -o ...

Or is it the application that is making the write call that determines which value is used?

I would like to mount my NFS partition in such a way that all WRITE Calls are UNSTABLE, but they are going as FILE_SYNC.  The added latency from my NFS server is unacceptable.  If I could force the WRITE Calls to UNSTABLE, then the latency would be drastically improved.

The mount is already set for async, but the WRITE Calls are still FILE_SYNC.

Here is the output from mount:

`X.X.X.X:/srv/nfs/share1 on /mnt/data type nfs (rw,relatime,vers=3,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,hard,nolock,proto=tcp,timeo=100,retrans=2,sec=sys,mountaddr=X.X.X.X,mountvers=3,mountport=54399,mountproto=udp,local_lock=all,addr=X.X.X.X)`